# Улучшенный\Стандартный Quicksort C++

Tags: c++, сортировка, qsort

Ищу алгоритм быстрой сортировки на C++. Просто учитель просил именно как он реализован в C++(cstdlib\stdlib).  Еще хотелось бы посмотреть на улучшенную быструю сортировку, например, если кусок меньше 10 элементов, то применять insertSort. Если мой источник не врет, то это даст прирост в скорости до 15%.
Еще не откажусь от интересных фактов\инфы по quicksort.

Comment: а что вам мешает посмотреть самому,? Где-нибудь рядом со своим компилятором находите папочку include и смотрите. Кстати, не факт что у разных компиляторов реализация стандартых библиотек будет совпадать.

Comment: @Mirdin С++ это тебе не java, где все библиотеки можно посмотреть, тут чтобы отрыть код нужно попотеть, в папочках инклюд одни названия классов, методов и переменных(

Comment: @nick_n_a мое задание рассказать другим людям про квик сорт. Интернет огромен и на 90% сайтов один и тот же материал под разным углом. Просмотреть весь интернет нет возможности, вот и спросил вдруг кто интересную ссылку подкинет. Прошу прощения, если мой вопрос выглядит как "сделайте всю работу за меня".

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле сложный. В реальности вызывается ф-ция sort и редко кто думает что за ней. Если обьекты большие-сортируют как правило ссылки на обьекты. Скорость сортировки это - (время перестановка существующих елементов или создание нового массива элементов)*(время поиска/сравнения элементов). В реальности кастомный способ сортировки используется в очень редких случаях (игры, системное ПО). Так как скорость сортировки зависит от входного набора данных, то для каждого конкретного случая нужна своя сортировка. Думаю для раскрытия других способов сортировки это надо уточнить в заголовке.

Answer (score 5):

Стандарты `С` и `C++` не описывают внутреннюю реализацию функции `qsort`, это же относится абсолютно ко всему. В стандарте описывается лишь видимое поведение, поэтому вопрос "как это реализованно в С++" некорректен.

Если же искать конкретную реализацию, то [вот](http://aturing.umcs.maine.edu/~sudarshan.chawathe/200801/capstone/n/qsort.c) вариант, который предположительно используется в `linux` системах.

Comment: Я кстати однажды сравнивал `qsort` библиотечную (minGW) и самописную, реализированную в лоб. По производительность отличий толком не обнаружил.

Answer (score 3):

Берите любую правильную сортировку Quicksort на С++. Стандарт не накладывает условий на используемую в С++ сортировку, поэтому внутри компилятора может быть как Quicksort, так и совершенно любая другая сортировка с условием O(N log N). К примеру, в том же GCC, если верить вики, используется гибридный алгоритм [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) и который можно посмотреть скачав исходники.

Qiucksort: http://aturing.umcs.maine.edu/~sudarshan.chawathe/200801/capstone/n/qsort.c

Introsort: http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h